# Unable to Set Value of Select Menu with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've set the value of select menus before using jQuery but this situation is proving to be much more difficult. I am attempting to reset the values of several select menus based on the input values from other fields. I want to preserve any previously selected values though, which is where I am getting hung up. Currently, I am unable to set a desired value of a select menu using jQuery and a $.each() loop. Below is the code along with the explanation of what I am trying to do in the comments.

```js
// When a user blurs from one of the 12 diagnosisCodeInput fields
$(document).on('blur', '.diagnosisCodeInput', function() {
  // For each of the pointer select menus...
  // Get the currently selected value
  // Populate each of the pointer select menus with the new diagnosisCodeInput values
  // Re-select the selected pointer value

  $('.pointer').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val()); // This shows the correct value

    // Get correct pointer
    let pointer = $(this);
    // Get the selected value of the pointer
    let selected = $(this).val();

    // Get all of the diagnosisCodeInput values and re-create each of the pointer select menus
    var searchIDs = $('.diagnosisCodeInput').map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    $('.pointer').empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').html(''));
    $.each(searchIDs, function(val, text) {
      if (text != '') {
        $('.pointer').append($('<option></option>').val(text).html(text));
      }
    });

    console.log($(this).val()); // This shows empty string
    console.log(selected); // This shows proper value (same as above console log)
    console.log(pointer); // This shows the proper value

    // console.log( pointer.children().find('option[value="' + selected + '"]') );

    // Re-select the previously selected value (this is the part not working)
    // pointer.val(selected).change(); // Does not work
    // pointer.children().find('option[value="' + selected + '"]').prop('selected', true); // Does not work
    // pointer.find('option[value="' + selected + '"]').attr('selected', true); // Does not work
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit and add relevant HTML in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
$.each(searchIDs, function(val, text) {
  if (text != '')
  {
    $('.pointer').append($('<option>',
    {
        value: val,
        text: text
    }));
  }
});
```

then you should be able to select with pointer.val(selected);